# sudo pip3 install on google cloud functions

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, pip, google-cloud-functions, requirements.txt

I have a module called kiteconnect that I want to use for a google cloud function. Issue is that a regular `pip3 install kiteconnect` throws out this error:

```
Deployment failure:
Build failed: `pip_download_wheels` had stderr output:
WARNING: Legacy build of wheel for 'kiteconnect' created no files.
Command arguments: /opt/python3.7/bin/python3.7 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-wheel-o4rwz7_o/kiteconnect/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-wheel-o4rwz7_o/kiteconnect/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-8rkohvc1
Command output: [use --verbose to show]
ERROR: Failed to build one or more wheels

error: `pip_download_wheels` returned code: 1; Error ID: 35132919
```

The way to get around this error is the use a `sudo pip3 install kiteconnect` but I'm not sure how to specify that through the `requirements.txt` file used for cloud functions.

Any suggestion on what I can do to get my function to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error indicates that one of your dependencies is uninstallable.

It looks like the `kiteconnect` dependency is currently incompatible with Python 3.7, which is the Python version Cloud Functions uses in it's runtime: https://github.com/zerodhatech/pykiteconnect/issues/55

You'll need to wait until the maintainers release a new version that is compatible with Python 3.7.

Comment: Hi Dustin, I get that. Is there a way to `sudo pip3 install` or `pip3 instal --user` the dependency? That's how I get it to run on my local machine.

Comment: No, there is not. This is an issue with `kiteconnect`, not with Cloud Functions.